# Emacs org-mode capture without expansions

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I've been trying to make an org capture template for storing quick ideas to my current project so I can get back to what I'm working on and evaluating the notes later.

This is the template code:

> (setq org-capture-templates '(
>    ("a" "quick notes" entry (file+olp "~/myproject" "NOTES" "IDEAS")
>      "") ))

When I hit `C-c c a *** invent flying light bulb RET` this is what I expect the target will look like:

```
* NOTES
** IDEAS
*** invent flying light bulb
```

Instead I get:

```
* NOTES
** IDEAS
*** invent flying light bulb
    $THE-HEADING-THAT-THE-CURSOR-IS-ON
```

That is: whatever headline the cursor touches when 'org-capture is called is inserted along with my note. When I delete that string this appears:

> [[file:~/$PATH-TO-FILE-I-WAS-WORKING-ON][]]

I haven't chosen any template expansions so why is this stuff inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **entry**, the last field should *not* be blank.  The example in the frequently asked questions for org-mode uses **item** when leaving the last field blank.

```lisp
(setq org-capture-templates '(
  ("a" "quick notes" entry
    (file+olp "~/Desktop/myproject.org" "NOTES" "IDEAS")
      "*** %?") ))
```